# Script dies after receiving SIGUSR1/SIGUSR2

Tags: bash, shell

I have a simple bash script that listens to `SIGUSR{1,2}` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

trigger() {
  echo "receiving signal"
}

echo $$
trap trigger USR1 USR2
sleep inf
```

So I ran the script and then ran:

```
kill -USR1 -$PID # where $PID is the PID printed by the script
```

`receiving signal` is printed, but then the script just dies afterwards.

Is there a way to prevent this, so that the script can keep on listening to `SIGUSR{1,2}` signals?

Comment: ? That's not really the problem. But I managed to solved it by using `trap 'trigger && sleep inf' USR1 USR2`. It seems that the `sleep inf` at the bottom gets terminated when trap runs. Someone more knowledgeable can feel free to expand on this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

trigger() {
  echo 'receiving signal'
}

echo "$$"
trap 'trigger' USR1 USR2

while true; do
    sleep inf
done
```

The process exits `sleep` when the signal is received so it can handle that signal so if you want your process to sleep again after the signal has been handled then you need to put the call to `sleep` in a loop (or call it from the `trap` but that could get ugly with general code).

Here it is running under `set -x` so you can see the lines being hit as I send it 2 USR1 signals from another terminal:

```
$ bash -x ./tst.sh
+ echo 2014
2014
+ trap trigger USR1 USR2
+ true
+ sleep inf
User defined signal 1
++ trigger
++ echo 'receiving signal'
receiving signal
+ true
+ sleep inf
User defined signal 1
++ trigger
++ echo 'receiving signal'
receiving signal
+ true
+ sleep inf
```